# Rails using wrong model sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models `User` and `Google::User`. Rails sometimes understand the difference between the two but then confuses the two models. Here is my output from rails console. Both the time I get output from `User` model.

```
irb(main):004:0> User
=> User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: inet, last_sign_in_ip: inet, name: string, location: string, website: string, github: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

irb(main):005:0> Google::User
=> Google::User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: inet, last_sign_in_ip: inet, name: string, location: string, website: string, github: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

I understand that both are perfectly namespaced. Then why would this be happening?

Comment: Try `::Google::User` .

Comment: Tried, doesn't work.

Comment: On the console, that is fields of `User` or `Google::User`?

Comment: They both are the fields from `User`

Comment: Interesting.. I've actually came across a similar issue. I have `Game` and `PSN::Game` in my app which worked fine for more than 2 years . I don't know exactly what caused this all of a sudden, but I had to add this in my `PSN::Game` model `self.table_name = 'psn_games'` . It only happens in production though, development works fine without that 'fix'

Comment: I'll try your fix. I'm facing this in development though.

Comment: if you are using single table, then specify type column. Otherwise will not separate...

Comment: Can you show the `autoload_path`?